# Changing laravel file structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am new to Laravel and PHP programming. I am building a web application using laravel framework. When I create project using `composer create-project` it creates laravel files inside the laravel folder and I move all the files out of laravel folder and delete the empty laravel folder as belo.

```
-root folder
--app
--bootstrap
--config
--database
--public 
-----------
```

After, I pushed the project to github and clone it from another computer and to add laravel files I execute `composer install`. Now laravel framework files are created inside a laravel folder instead of root directory.

```
-root folder
--app
--bootstrap 
--config
--database
--public
--laravel
----app
----bootstrap 
----config
----database
----public
```

How can I change the location, composer create the laravel framework files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install laravel with composer then you should follow bellow this way:

Firstly install **[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)** according to your operating system.And then if you use `xampp` then create a project folder or run a command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` this will create a root folder and a sub-folder named laravel.

Your problem is that when you secondly `clone` git form github that time you mixed up the main root folder that's why its duplicated.

I think you should re-install again according the given procedure.Hope this will solve your problem.

**Another way:** if in your pc have installed composer then you just clone the git and after that in the root folder (cloned git folder) run the command `composer update`.It should solve your problem.

**Tricks:** For opening root folder with command for windows operating system. Press select the root folder and Ctrl + Shift + right button of mouse then click the options `Open command window here` .

**[LARAVEL DOC.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create Laravel project

**composer create-project laravel/laravel YourProjectName**